# How to select text by tag name in element?

Tags: javascript

I need to select title which is in `div` wrapped by `h2`, so i do something like this `this.getElementsByTagName('h2')` where this is current div in which is h2 - it returns current `h2` element, but when i trying to get `innerHTML` or `innerText` it return null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it returns current h2 element, but when i trying to get innerHTML or innerText it return null. What am I doing wrong?

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not an element. The list doesn't have `innerHTML`, but each of its *elements* does, e.g.:

```
var list = this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
if (list[0]) {
    title = list[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Or if you're **sure** that it will exist:

```
title = this.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML;
```

...but that will throw an exception if there are no h2's found.

Comment: So i think it's better to use `jQuery(this).find('h2').text()` as it is already included...

Comment: @Kirix: Er, yes. You didn't say you were using jQuery. :-)

Comment: yes, but i trying to reach best performance so where it is possible i use pain js.

Answer (score 1):

No, `this.getElementsByTagName('h2')` returns an array of elements with tag name `h2`.

You have to iterate the array and access the correct element you want.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You should capture the first element of the node list that's returned by `getElementsByTagName()`:

   ```
   var h2 = this.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
   ```
2. Different browsers use different properties to retrieve the tag contents:

   ```
   var title = h2.textContent || h2.innerText || null;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have done a small mistake. Because , `this.getElementByTagName('h2')` will return you a list ( of tags).

Being your tag is the first element as `[0]`

you can use

```
var v= this.getElementsByTagName('h2');
var yourdata=v[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state getElementsByTagName returns an array.

Another option would be to use querySelector (supported only by modern browsers so check what you need to support first)

Running querySelector on this page gives the following:-

```
window.document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML //#>
"<a href="/questions/16516643/how-to-select-text-by-tag-name-in-element" class="question-hyperlink">How to select text by tag name in element?</a>"
```

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector)

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)